# What's the obligation for using ubuntu font in my application?

Tags: fonts

What's the obligation for using ubuntu font in my application?

Do I have to release my application under UFL-1.0, in case if I including ubuntu font in my application?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/font-licence) is the official Ubuntu font licence.

> The requirement for fonts to remain under this licence does not require any document created using the fonts or their derivatives to be published under this licence, as long as the primary purpose of the document is not to be a vehicle for the distribution of the fonts.

According to my understanding you can freely choose the license for your application.

For more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(typeface)#Ubuntu_Font_Licence) is an article from Wikipedia describing the Ubuntu font licence.

**Disclaimer:** I'm only a developer and this is only my opinion.